# How to run background Service in Oreo Just like below oreo without starting foreground service?

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app that needs to run always in the background and listen for server changes. When I target API below Oreo, I am able to run service in the background. But now I'm targeting the API version 28. But Oreo changes not allowing to run in background service.

Solution: I need to make it the foreground service ( but I don't want to make a foreground service ).

I want to at least run my service for 30 minutes in the background. I have used JobService and JobIntentService. But oreo kills these service after sometime.

What can be the possible solution for that?

Comment: `"I need to make it foreground service ( but I don't want to make a foreground service )."` - it really make no sense - whats wrong in foreground service? that small notification icon?

Comment: share your logcat if app crashes. Show us some code we can understand better.

Comment: @pskink not wrong with foreground service. Actually, this is requirement that We don't want to show foreground service notification.

Comment: There a solution, We can set min sdk version below Oreo. this way service can always run in background. But we need to make app targeting the latest API Version 28.

Comment: I want to run Service in background, which records audio for 30 minutes without showing the notification. And My app is in background when I have to start that service.

Comment: Just like to record phone Call, If call comes, I will start service to record call without showing user the foreground notification.

Comment: Yes, I have read. But there's should be way a way, to atleast run service for 30 minutes ?

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround to do it.

Comment: Just because service always runs in background. consumes resources like battery, cpu quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't like you can't subtract a number using the Plus "+" operator. If a thing is though/developed/created for ONE SPECIFIC behavior it's common that this thing works only in that way. For Security reasons developers are obligated to create Foreground services to let the users know that there is some Process that is working in background. It's a good practice.

In conclusion: you can't.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this worked for me

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     Intent ServiceG = new Intent(context, ClipboardService.class);
     context.startService(ServiceG);
} else {
     Intent ServiceG = new Intent(context, ClipboardJobService.class);
     //context.startService(ServiceG);
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         context.startForegroundService(ServiceG);
     }else {
         context.startService(ServiceG);
     }
}
```

ClipboardJobService extends JobService class and
ClipboardService extends Service class

i hoped this helped you...

Comment: can you please share the Job Service implementation ?

Comment: I have tried it Just like as you mentioned ? But not worked for me. You can check the below answer and code

Answer (score -1):

@Mahendra Gohil, I started job service just like as you mentioned, here's my code,

- what i'm doing

I'm starting a recording to record in background, but it's stop automatically after few minutes. How to keep this service alive ? can you share your job Service implementation.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class BackgroundJobService extends JobService {

    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    static int time = 0;
    static int timeInterval = 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        startRecording(this, params);
        addRecursiveTaskHandler(params);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }

    static RecMicToMp3 recorder = null;

    public void startRecording(final Context context, final JobParameters parameters) {
        stopRecording(context);
        String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/aaa.mp3";
        try {
            recorder = new RecMicToMp3(file, 8000);
            recorder.start();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private void addRecursiveTaskHandler(final JobParameters parameters) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ++time;
                if (time <= 15) {
                    addRecursiveTaskHandler(parameters);
                } else {
                    stopRecording(getApplicationContext());
                    jobFinished(parameters, false);
                }
            }
        }, timeInterval);
    }

    public void stopRecording(final Context context) {
        if ((null != recorder)) {
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```